# How to disconnect ESP8266 from the access point permanently?

Tags: esp8266

I connected an ESP8266 to an AP using the following set of commands:

```
AT
AT+CWMODE=1
AT+RST
AT+CWLAP
AT+CWJAP="***","***"
```

Now the problem is I can't get it to disconnect from the AP. I tried running `AT+CWQAP`. While it disconnects when I run this command, when I unplug the ESP8266 and plug it back in, it automatically reconnects to the AP. I tried changing the mode + reset as well but they do not permanently disconnect the ESP8266.

Comment: use `AT+CWAUTOCONN=0` or clear the flash memory with esptool